# Adding AWS Amplify to iOS Swift app with multiple Targets does not work

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add amplify to an existing iOS (Swift) application with multiple targets. After running amplify init in the root of the project, the cli gives the following feedback:

> Updating Xcode project:
>  xcodeProject: Target Fan app not found
> -- Recovery suggestion: Manually add Amplify files to your Xcode project.

The amplify folder is created in the project root, and I also see both awsconfiguration.json and amplifyconfiguration.json files.

I added the amplify packages to the project and added Amplify.configure() to the AppDelegate as described in the aws docs on https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/create-application/q/platform/ios/.

When I run the application, I see the following in the console:

> Failed to find Amplify configuration.
> An error occurred setting up Amplify: ConfigurationError: Could not load default `amplifyconfiguration.json` file
> Recovery suggestion: Expected to find the file, `amplifyconfiguration.json` in the app bundle at `/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxx/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxx/App.app`, but it was not present. Either add amplifyconfiguration.json to your app's "Copy Bundle Resources" buildphase, or invoke `Amplify.configure()` with a configuration object that you load from a custom path.

I assume this is because of the 'not found' error in the init step, but I would need different configurations for the different targets. So I follow the suggestion and invoke the configuration with a config object as suggested with the code I found [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift/issues/460)

```
let apiConfig = APICategoryConfiguration(
plugins: ["awsAPIPlugin":
    [
        "myendpointname": [
            "endpointType": "GraphQL",
            "endpoint": "REPLACE",
            "region": "REPLACE",
            "authorizationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
        ]
    ]
])
let config = AmplifyConfiguration(api: apiConfig)
Amplify.configure(config)
```

But now I get:

> No plugin found for configuration key `awsAPIPlugin`. Add a plugin for that key.

I can see in the target settings that the plugin is added to the target that I am running, so I get the feeling that this is also related to the failed final step in the amplify init where amplify was not able to find the target.

[image: Plugins]

My question is; how can I initiate amplify in a iOS project with multiple targets?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the `amplifyconfiguration.json` file and `awsconfiguration.json` file to the project? After they're added to the root folder of your app, you still have to manually add them to your app, as explained [here](https://amplify-ios-workshop.go-aws.com/20_getting_started/30_configuring_amplify.html#add-amplify-configuration-files-to-the-project)